# Android media player null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I want to play a sound file with mediaplayer. I am getting error message when I am playing an audio file. ("Unfortunately, the process horizontalviewpaging has stopped" ) Please help me, thanks.

The code is;

```
package ro.ovidiuconeac.horizontalviewswiping;
import ro.ovidiuconeac.horizontalviewswiping.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomPageChangeListener extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,     OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer soundplay;
private Button buttonBlue   =   null;
private Button buttonYellow =   null;
private Button buttonRed    =   null;
private Activity context    =   null;

/**
 * Constructor
 */ 

public CustomPageChangeListener(Activity context) {
this.context = context;

}

public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {

switch (position) {
    case 0 : {
        buttonBlue = (Button)    context.findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);
        buttonBlue.setOnClickListener(this);

        break;
    }
    case 1 : {
        buttonYellow = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow);
        buttonYellow.setOnClickListener(this);
        break;
    }
    case 2 : {
        buttonRed = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
        buttonRed.setOnClickListener(this);

        break;
    }
    }   
}

public void onClick(View v) {

// Click button blue
if (buttonBlue != null && v.getId() == buttonBlue.getId()) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Blue screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

// Click button yellow
if (buttonYellow != null && v.getId() == buttonYellow.getId()) {

    //  Toast.makeText(context, "Yellow screen",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    playMusic();
}

// Click button red
if (buttonRed != null && v.getId() == buttonRed.getId()) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Red screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}   
}

public void playMusic () {
soundplay = new MediaPlayer();
    try {   
    soundplay = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bangyeni);
    soundplay.setVolume(1, 1);
    soundplay.start();

}
catch (Exception e){
Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   
}
```

Logcat;

```
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     ro.ovidiuconeac.horizontalviewswiping.CustomPageChangeListener.onClick(CustomPageChangeList    ener.java:80)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at         android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
> 09-01 08:38:04.964: E/AndroidRuntime(631): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
```

Comment: Where's the onCreate method? Why do you need a constructor for your Activity?

Comment: I don't understand your constructor. Why are you using another context in this activity? It causes a huge memory leak and may create serious problems if you try to use it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext()
```

There is the Nullpointer

If forgot where, but at some class the Android documentation is wrong! it is asking a context, but is not good which I gave.

Try this:

```
MediaPlayer.create(this
```

Answer (score 0):

First loose the line soundplay = new MediaPlayer(); And change playMusic as follows.
I assume you have the bangyeni in the raw folder of your resources.

```
public void playMusic () {
//soundplay = new MediaPlayer();  <--- not needed
    try {   
    soundplay = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bangyeni);
    soundplay.setVolume(1, 1);
    soundplay.start();

}
```